# user preferences window won't load

Tags: customization

I just got Blender and it works fine for the most part, but when I open the preferences window it's blank and white. Does anyone know why this might be?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Which version of Blender is it? 2.80 is still in beta, so if that's the version you have it's likely just a bug that hasn't been fixed yet. You can also try switching an editor, say the 3d view, into the preferences window. In 2.8 the place to do this is at the top left of the 3d view, otherwise it's at the bottom right (the little menu where you can select a different editor).

Comment: It's version 2.79 from the windows store. What is supposed to happen when I switch the editor? I think I did it but it just says "Save user preferences" on the top bar and nothing else happens.

Comment: If it's 2.79 I would double check your graphics card drivers, and make sure they're all up to date. All of blenders editors are interchangeable, including that top bar with the file menu, which is what happened in your case. That was simply just to test if it was the user preferences or the new window, and it appears to be the new window. If you want to access the user preferences until you figure things out, you can switch out the 3d view at the bottom left (not bottom right, my bad) where there is a little cube icon. Then you can switch it back once you've adjust what you want.

Comment: Oh, I understand now thank you. Problem solved.